# What is the computational complexity of the calculation of $ \Psi(x) $?

Tags: computational-complexity, nonlinear-optimization, combinatorial-optimization, integer-programming, convolution

What is the computational complexity of the calculation of $ \Psi(x) $ described below:

Let $\left\{ f_i : \{0,1,\dots,m\} \to \mathbb{R} \right\}_{i=1}^n$. For each $x \in  \{0,1,\dots,m\}$ we consider
$$ \Psi(x):= \min_{\begin{array}{c}
   \alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_n x_n=x \\
   x_i\in \{0,1,\dots,m\}\\
   \alpha_i \in \{0,1\}
 \end{array}}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$$

Comment: Why include $\alpha_i$?  Simpler to have $$\Psi(x):= \min_{\begin{array}{c}
   x_1+\dots+x_n=x \\
   x_i\in \{0,1,\dots,m\}
 \end{array}}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(x_i)$$

Comment: The problem you say is not the original one. What you say is the infimal convolution.

Comment: OK, I see.  You have $f_i(x_i)$ and not $f_i(\alpha_i x_i)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant of the integer equality [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) and can be solved via dynamic programming.  The complexity is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem#Computational_complexity).

For a DP recursion, first define
$$\Psi_k(x):=\min_{\begin{array}{c}
   \alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_k x_k=x \\
   x_i\in \{0,1,\dots,m\}\\
   \alpha_i \in \{0,1\}
 \end{array}}\sum_{i=1}^k f_i(x_i)$$
and then condition on $\alpha_k$ and $x_k$ to obtain
$$\Psi_k(x) = \min_{\alpha_k, x_k}\{f_k(x_k)+\Psi_{k-1}(x-\alpha_k x_k)\}$$
You want to compute $\Psi_n(x)$.